# Combine specific columns (variable length) into one column - excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, office365

So the situation is that I would like to copy **4 columns with variable lengths** into one column containing all the data from these 4. The problem is I **loose data** in the process.

As an example it should be 693 rows but I only get 648 rows all in all.
I'm relatively new to VBA and have come up with these lines of code.

```
Sub Copy()

Dim RngA As Range, RngB As Range, RngC As Range, RngD As Range, Rng As Range
Set RngA = Range(Range("I2"), Range("I" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
Set RngB = Range(Range("J2"), Range("J" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
Set RngC = Range(Range("K2"), Range("K" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
Set RngD = Range(Range("L2"), Range("L" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    Range("O2").Resize(RngA.Count).Value = RngA.Value
    Range("O" & RngA.Count + 1).Resize(RngB.Count).Value = RngB.Value
    Range("O" & RngB.Count + 1).Resize(RngC.Count).Value = RngC.Value
    Range("O" & RngC.Count + 1).Resize(RngD.Count).Value = RngD.Value


With Sheets("Keywords")
    Columns("O:O").Sort Key1:=.Range("=O1"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: You are not cumulatively adding the number of cells of all previous ranges, e.g. `Range("O" & RngB.Count + 1)` does not take into account the size of RngA.

Comment: Any reason you don't use the [`CONCATENATE()` function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/CONCATENATE-function-8f8ae884-2ca8-4f7a-b093-75d702bea31d) as formula instead of VBA? In column O use `=CONCATENATE(I:I, J:J, K:K, L:L)`.

Comment: @Peh CONCATENATE will  not line each column below the next it will return all four of that row in the one cell.

Comment: @ScottCraner you can activate line breaks in column O and use `=CONCATENATE(I:I, "#", J:J, "#", K:K, "#", L:L)` where the `#` has to be replaced by a line break (Alt+Enter) so this is possible (I just can't show it here due to formatting issues in comments).

Comment: @Peh but that will still put all four of the current row in one cell with line breaks.  not each value in its own cell so it can be sorted properly.

Comment: @ScottCraner huh? then I obviously misunderstood his goal :( my apologize

Comment: @Peh - the OP wants the first column of x items at the top of column O, then the next column of y items underneath those in column O etc.

Comment: @SJR ya thanks I got it after I saw your code. Just got on the wrong track early.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See my comment above, but here is an alternative approach using arrays which saves having to set up multiple similarly-named range variables.(Btw am assuming everything is on the Keywords sheet.)

```
Sub Copy()

Dim vRng(1 To 4) As Range, i As Long

With Sheets("Keywords")
    For i = LBound(vRng) To UBound(vRng)
        Set vRng(i) = .Range(.Cells(2, i + 8), .Cells(.Rows.Count, i + 8).End(xlUp))
    Next i
    For i = LBound(vRng) To UBound(vRng)
        .Range("O" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(2).Resize(vRng(i).Count).Value = vRng(i).Value
    Next i
    .Columns("O:O").Sort Key1:=.Range("O1"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast solution! It works like a charm :)